# Partial view action resulting in 404 error

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this code snippet in my view:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.Partial("_PostCommentPartial", new PostCommentViewModel(Model.Id))
}
```

On my partial view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostComment", "SecondComments",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
        UpdateTargetId = "comments"
    }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TicketId)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Content)

<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" />
</div>
}
```

My controller:

```
public class SecondCommentsController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult PostComment(PostCommentViewModel comment)
    {
        // some codes here
    }
}
```

When I'm clicking the submit button, I am getting a 500 error. Please advise.

**EDIT** My base controller class that was inherited by my controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected ITicketSystemData Data { get; private set; }

    protected User UserProfile { get; private set; }

    public BaseController(ITicketSystemData data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }

    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        this.UserProfile = this.Data.Users.All().Where(u => u.UserName == requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();

        return base.BeginExecute(requestContext, callback, state);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your requested URL matches your controller + action names. `Ajax.BeginForm("PostComment", "SecondComment",` controller name should be "SecondComments" to match `public class SecondCommentsController`.

Comment: What is this BaseController class ? Can you post the code ?

Comment: I notice that you change the error code from 404 to 500, I am right ? if so, it changes the full picturre, now your action method PostComment is been hit on debug probally ? If yes, which line it throws the exception ?